# What is the need to verify reCaptcha in the server side?

Tags: security, recaptcha, brute-force

I am implementing google reCaptcha. In the Google documentation, they say the way to do it. The documentation suggests server side validation of captcha. I wanted to know why we need to verify it in the server side as it is already verified in the UI side from the google server. Is it a suggested to implement captcha in the UI side alone with no validation in the server? What are the problems(if any) if done in UI alone.

Answer (score 8):

a example would be: you're creating a register form and want to prevent bots to create a account on your site, you need to verify it serverside, because in the background you're sending a request which will look something like this:

```
POST /register 1.1 HTTP
Host: www.example.com

{"username":"example","email:"hey@gmail.de","captcha-token":"123984f729340fmu2q34f9"}
```

and if you dont send the captcha-token with the request or the server doesnt validate it,  this bot could just spam this request **without** loading the frontend page. Please mind in head, that bots dont visit your "UI" (frontend page). Just verify **everything** serverside like text length, bad characters, rate limits...